# Возможность создания треугольника

Tags: javascript

Есть огромный массив чисел  [430, 735, 19, 922, 536, 47, 750, 686, 60, 545, 836, 683, 828, 748, 301, 678, 297, 546...], каждые три числа (430, 735, 19), (922, 536, 47) и т.д. - это стороны треугольника, необходимо понять - сколько треугольников возможно (возможный треугольник - это когда сумма длин любых двух сторон больше третьей)

Comment: Просто длину массива разделить на три незя ?

Comment: @MonkeyMutant а если подумать? Конечно нельзя. Уже из первых трех чисел нельзя сделать треугольник. И из вторых.

Comment: @Эникейщик Возможно я ошибся... но я как свгшник переспросил...с геометрией не дружу..

Comment: @MonkeyMutant ну так в вопросе же сразу написано, в каком случае можно сделать треугольник

Comment: В цикле `i+=3` условие `if (m[i] > (m[i + 1] + m[i + 2]) || m[i + 1] > (m[i] + m[i + 2]) || m[i + 2] > (m[i] + m[i + 1]) ) count++`

Comment: @Rudi только не ``||``, а ``&&``

Comment: @Эникейщик Почему? `(возможный треугольник - это когда сумма длин любых двух сторон больше третьей)` Не пойму, что я упустил?

Comment: @Эникейщик Всё понял. Туплю..

Answer (score 2):

Самое простое решение

```js
const array = [430, 735, 19, 922, 536, 47, 750, 686, 60, 545, 836, 683, 828, 748, 301, 1];
let triangleCount = 0;

for (let i = 0, n = array.length; i < n; i += 3) {
  let a = array[i],
    b = array[i + 1],
    c = array[i + 2];

  if (a == undefined || b == undefined || c == undefined) {
    break;
  }

  if (a + b > c && a + c > b && b + c > a) {
    triangleCount++;
  }
}

console.log(triangleCount);
```

Answer (score 0):

Как решать: брать последовательно по три числа и проверять, можно ли из них сделать треугольник. Если можно, то увеличивать счетчик на один.